libssh2 api support in c to use both private key and password together
I have a remote host that has public/private key and password both enabled. They have to be done together in order to obtain a connection. I am using the libssh2 api and have no idea how to code that if its even supported?
    sshrc = libssh2_userauth_publickey_fromfile(session, username, pubkey, privkey, password);

libssh2_userauth_password(session, username, mslpubkey);
both of these routines work perfectly when its an either or situation.
